# Why am I Able to load x64 assembly into AnyCPU Prefer 32 bit executable?

Tags: c#, .net, 32bit-64bit, assemblies

I am working on a tool that loads different assemblies using `System.Reflection`'s method  `Assembly.Load`
Here is what i  get
On a 64bit OS, if application configured with :

- x64 loads x64 & AnyCPU Assembly
- x86 loads x86 & AnyCPU Assembly
- AnyCPU loads x64 & AnyCPU Assembly

Now when it's configured with AnyCPU Prefer 32 bit on 64 bit OS,it will be running on 32bit process as it said here

> In .NET 4.5 and Visual Studio 11 the cheese has been moved. The
> default for most .NET projects is again AnyCPU, but there is more than
> one meaning to AnyCPU now. There is an additional sub-type of AnyCPU,
> “Any CPU 32-bit preferred”, which is the new default (overall, there
> are now five options for the /platform C# compiler switch: x86,
> Itanium, x64, anycpu, and anycpu32bitpreferred). When using the
> "Prefer 32-Bit" flavor of AnyCPU, the semantics are as follows:
>
> - If the process runs on a 32-bit Windows system, it runs as a 32-bit    process. IL is compiled to x86 machine code.
> - If the process runs on a 64-bit Windows system, it runs as a 32-bit    process. IL is compiled to x86 machine code.
> - If the process runs on an ARM Windows system, it runs as a 32-bit    process. IL is compiled to ARM machine code.
>
> **The difference, then, between “Any CPU 32-bit preferred” and “x86” is
> only this: a .NET application compiled to x86 will fail to run on an
> ARM Windows system, but an “Any CPU 32-bit preferred” application will
> run successfully.**

My Question is : Why it loads x64 assembly without any problem? isn't that a strange behaviour?

I have seen this question [ODP.NET x64 ANYCPU and Prefer 32-bit setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15038742/odp-net-x64-anycpu-and-prefer-32-bit-setting) that support this proposition

Comment: Are you on a Windows x64 ?

Comment: @OlivierRogier yes

Comment: @OlivierRogier That's an entirely different question: it's not about .NET, at all. The answer is different with .NET assemblies.

Comment: @OlivierRogier The question is not about whether it's possible to load a **native** DLL of one bitness into a process of another bitness (although that forms part of an answer, I suppose). It's about what the JIT is doing when you load an assembly with one set of flags specifying AnyCPU, etc, into an AppDomain whose entry point assembly had a different set of flags. Closing this question in favour of the one you found will not answer OP's question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET assemblies (exe and dll) don't contain x86/x64 assembly. They contain IL (intermediate language), which is architecture-independent. At runtime, the JIT turns the IL into x86/x64 machine code, as appropriate.

The "Any CPU" and "Prefer 32-bit" settings, etc, only change some bits in the header of the assembly, which tells the JIT what to emit at runtime. Only the bits in the header of the .exe matter: the exe dictates what the JIT will emit, and if the JIT is emitting e.g. x86 for the exe, it will do the same for all other assemblies which are loaded into that process.

Now, it might be a bad idea to load a dll which has the "x86" flag set into a process which the JIT is emitting x64 for: presumably that dll has a reason for specifying x86, and that's probably because it's invoking some native code which is compiled for x86. If you force it to run inside an x64 process, then it won't be able to invoke that x86 native code any more.

(Note that the landscape has moved since that quote you found: .NET Core now ignores "Prefer 32-bit", and AnyCPU defaults to x64).

Comment: I get that part, As you said Prefer 32-bit only change bits in the header to tell JIT what to emit at runtime, now Prefer 32 bit Assembly will JIT to x86 code and the x64 assembly that i load will JIT to x64, Isn't that strange?

Comment: No. Like I said, the bits in the header of the **exe** determine the bitness of the **entire process**. If the exe says "x86", **everything** gets JIT'd to x86, including any DLLs whose header actually says something different, like "x64"

Answer (score 3):

The AnyCPU option allows the .NET virtual IL code in the executable binary file to be run on 32-bit as well as 64-bit computers.

AnyCPU prefers 32-bit indicates to run the process in 32-bit compatibility mode on x64 machines, unless of course some cause prevents that.

It is a parameter at runtime, not at compilation, as explained [@canton7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67607617/12031933).

[What is the purpose of the "Prefer 32-bit" setting in Visual Studio and how does it actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066638/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-prefer-32-bit-setting-in-visual-studio-and-how-does)

If the application loads 64-bit DLLs, it means the code is executed ([translated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140750/is-it-possible-to-compile-net-il-code-to-machine-code)) in 64-bits [native machine code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27249347/why-doesnt-c-sharp-compile-directly-to-machine-code), otherwise we would get a system error box.

Having a [virtual assembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes) for a [virtual OOP (single inheritance yet) computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode) is the purpose of DotNet.

If we look using any Task Manager we will see that the process is indeed x64 and not x32.

What is said in the following links about x32-x64 is valid for x64-x32:

[Is it possible to load a 64-bit dll into a 32-bit process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787556/is-it-possible-to-load-a-64-bit-dll-into-a-32-bit-process)

[Calling 32bit Code from 64bit Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128445/calling-32bit-code-from-64bit-process)

[Load 32bit DLL library in 64bit application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265023/load-32bit-dll-library-in-64bit-application)

[Process Interoperability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/process-interoperability)

To be able to load a DLL of a different architecture than the highest one, we need certain things like creating a sandbox. For example, Renoise can run 32-bit VST while the DAW is 64-bit.